# open href in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple videos to show in modal. I do not want to create modals for each button to show video seprate. I want to show all videos in single modal under all buttons.

I have found a function. It was working fine on older version of bootstrap but When I change to bootstrap 3.3.7 it did not show video in modal.

Here is my html.

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7iPoBjiFdho/" class="btn bootpopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupModal">Open modal</a>

<div id="popupModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is js function.

```
</script>
     <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.bootpopup').click(function(){
    var frametarget = $(this).attr('href');
  var targetmodal = $(this).attr('data-target');
  if (targetmodal == undefined) {
    targetmodal = '#popupModal';
  } else { 
    targetmodal = '#'+targetmodal;
  }
  if ($(this).attr('title') != undefined) {
    $(targetmodal+ ' .modal-header h3').html($(this).attr('title'));
    $(targetmodal+' .modal-header').show();
  } else {
     $(targetmodal+' .modal-header h3').html('');
    $(targetmodal+' .modal-header').hide();
  }  
    $(targetmodal).on('show', function () {
        $('iframe').attr("src", frametarget );   
    });
    $(targetmodal).modal({show:true});
  return false;

});

        });

        </script>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @George You mean by fiddle?

Comment: yes. create fiddle with your issue here https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, it should works now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.bootpopup').click(function(){
   var frametarget = $(this).attr('href');
   var targetmodal = $(this).attr('data-target');
   if (targetmodal === undefined) {
     targetmodal = '#popupModal';
   }

   if ($(this).attr('title') != undefined) {
     $(targetmodal+ ' .modal-header h3').html($(this).attr('title'));
     $(targetmodal+' .modal-header').show();
   } else {
     $(targetmodal+' .modal-header h3').html('');
     $(targetmodal+' .modal-header').hide();
   }   
   $('iframe').attr("src", frametarget );   

   $(targetmodal).modal({show:true});
   return false;
   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7nbj5jjj/

Comment: You're welcome :) you can also do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers